# inserting a li element at a specific location

Tags: jquery

i have a list of items that gets populated,i needed to add a specific li element to a specific location which i achieved by adding the following

```
function test() {
  $('#navbar-collapse-menu li:eq(0)').after('<li style="background:orange">Hello</li>') //this adds it to the position i want.
}
```

i called this function within another function that populates the list.

```
function getNestedLists(source, debpth) {
    test();
    var children = $(source).children('li');

    var nestedlist = $('<ul></ul>');

    if (children && children.length > 0) {

        getLinks(nestedlist, children, ++debpth);
    }

    return nestedlist.children('li').length > 0 ? nestedlist : null;

}
```

And

```
function getLinks(target, source, debpth) {

    $.each($(source).children('a'), function () {

        var item = $('<li></li>');

        if (debpth) {


            item.append($("<a href='" + $(this).attr('href') + "'><i class='fa fa-circle fa-fw' aria-hidden='true' style='font-size:6px;vertical-align:middle;padding-right:15px'></i>" + $(this).html() + "</a>"));
        }
        else {
            item.append($("<a href='" + $(this).attr('href') + "'>" + $(this).html() + "</a>"));
        }
        item.addClass('debpth' + (debpth ? debpth : 0).toString());
        target.append(item);   

        var nested = getNestedLists($(this).siblings('ul'), debpth ? debpth : 0);
        if (nested) {
            $.each(nested, function () {

                $(this).children('li').addClass('debpth' + (debpth ? debpth : 0).toString());

                target.append($(this).children('li'));
            });

        }

    });

}
```

the problem is that when i enter the test() function it gets called multiple times.If i call it outside the function it doesnt do anything.How can i structure this better?This is what its doing:

- Home
- hello // this is what gets inserted
- hello
- hello
- hello
- hello
- hello
- hello
- Tab1
- tab2

i only want the hello li to appear once as follows

- Home
- Hello
- Tab1
- tab2

Comment: how's you call function `getNestedLists`? let us know that

Comment: @AlivetoDie it gets used by another function getlinks()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `test()` inside any other function call it seperatly.

```
test();//call it seperatly not inside any function
```

Comment: @Sarah  glad to help you.:):)